# ViewDidLoad of TableView associated with UITabbarcontroller not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, mobile

I have a tab bar with 5 tabs and each tab has a view associated with it added in storyboard. In my third tab , I have a view associated with "Inbox Table View Controller". When I run the application and click on third tab, only the table appears with no data in it. But when I navigate to some other tab and click on third tab once again , then the data appears. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Where is your code !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. I also got stuck with this kind of issue recently. If you are still searching for the answer, try this.
There are some common errors that occur while working with the tableviews. I think you are stuck with one of those . Try to use [self.tablview reloadData] in your viewDidLoad method of the controller. It may work.
PS: Just a wild guess as you have not posted your code.